# Access the audio (PCM) buffer of a MediaElement

Tags: windows-phone-8, mediaelement

Is this possible in SL4 and/or Windows Phone to access the sound buffer once it is decoded and played in a `MediaElement`?

If, for instance, I'm playing an AAC file into a `MediaElement`, will there be a specific moment where the sound will be decoded in a stream and accessible via some C++ code?

Comment: Hum, 13 hours until a bounty. Stay tuned. I spent at least 40 hours trying to figure out how to decode AAC files on WP8.

Comment: Someone just +1 that, and I know that somewhere I have a Runtime Component to decode AAC to PCM very quickly on WP8, so I'll star it and add an answer once at home.